# Game starts all over again in android - How to prevent restart?

Tags: unity-game-engine, libgdx

If I pause my game by pressing the home button and then I enter into the game by touching the game icon on the home screen it starts all over again. How can I detect if a game instance is already loaded into memory and take it from where the game was paused?

Comment: Not a specialist never really tried it but if you look a the life cycle you have a resume state for android: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle .   also you marked as libgdx and unity?

Comment: I already use that resume method to return to the proper screen . This only works if you pause the game (when pressing the Home button for example) and then enter the game again by accessing it from the open instances menu that appears when you keep the HOME button pressed; it doesn't work if you click the app icon. I use libgdx as my game framework but If there is a solution to the pb. I guess it would be similar for both unity and libgdx.

Comment: ah ok sorry :) hopefully someone can help you

Comment: Sounds like you're using an older version of Android

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml , using the  element's launchMode attribute set to "singleTop" solved the issue.